# how can I redirect to my website without using www. prefix .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, no-www

when I am typing http://www.icpcc.example.org my site is opening but when I am typing http://icpcc.example.org a page is showing "come back page". what should I do in my htaccess file.

Comment: Hi Daksh. We would need more information to know how to help. It appears from your question that you have two sites configured; one at www.icpcc.example.org and one at icpcc.example.org. Do you intend to have two sites?

Comment: no, I have only one site but I want to access my single site with both the address with www. prefix and without www. prefix.

Comment: Understand. So what page is loading without the www? (the "come back page"?)

Comment: yes the page is showing " come back later"

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following once, make sure you clear your browser cache before checking these urls testing.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L]
```

Comment: where to place the htaccess file.

Comment: @DakshLohar, in your root folder from where you need to serve things from backend, you could play around with it :)

Comment: @DakshLohar, sorry but please be more descriptive in what you tried and what didn't work. Please do add more details and let me know then.

Comment: I am saying that my website  (HTTP://www.icpcc.poornima.org) is opening with the "www." prefix but when I am trying to redirect using (HTTP://icpcc.poornima.org) it's not working. And in my .htaccess file, I have written these lines:  " RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^icpcc.poornima.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.icpcc.poornima.org/$1 [L,R=301,NC]"

Comment: @DakshLohar, yeah I understand that and this solution does that. Did you try putting this in your htaccess file?

Comment: @DakshLohar, we need to check if your htaccess is working fine and getting picked up, please put some random text in your htaccess file(making backup of your current one for sure), restart apache and hit link if you get error like 500 internal error etc then it means its picking htaccess file or its not.

Comment: yes, an error occurred 500 internal server error.

Comment: @DakshLohar, ok, then go back to your actual htaccess file, restart apache once. Hit your link again and see what are the error logs you are getting and let me know then?

Comment: Do I have to change the htaccess file?

Comment: @DakshLohar, make it like the one I posted in answer and restart apache, then hit your link and check the logs what they say?

Comment: the page is saying "coming soon page" only.

Comment: and in console "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received." error is occurring.

Comment: @DakshLohar, NO not the page, logs for apache, there will be files named `errors.log`, `access.log` etc please look into them and post here.